# Pandas: How to ctrate DateTime index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

There is Pandas Dataframe as:

```
    year    month   count
0   2014    Jan     12
1   2014    Feb     10
2   2015    Jan     12
3   2015    Feb     10
```

How to create DateTime index from 'year' and 'month',so result would be :

```
              count
2014.01.31    12
2014.02.28    10
2015.01.31    12
2015.02.28    10
```

Comment: In your initial DataFrame you do not have day, so where do we find this column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for use and remove columns and add [`offsets.MonthEnd`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd.html):

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(df.pop('year').astype(str) + df.pop('month'), format='%Y%b')
df.index = dates + pd.offsets.MonthEnd()

print (df)
            count
2014-01-31     12
2014-02-28     10
2015-01-31     12
2015-02-28     10
```

Or:

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(df.pop('year').astype(str) + df.pop('month'), format='%Y%b')
df.index = dates + pd.to_timedelta(dates.dt.daysinmonth - 1, unit='d')

print (df)
            count
2014-01-31     12
2014-02-28     10
2015-01-31     12
2015-02-28     10
```